# Casting object[,] to string[]

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have an excel sheet returning back the Interop Excel Range in c#. What I am trying to do is cast the range.Value2 which comes back as rangeVal2 as [1,1] int [1,2] string [1,3] null. I wanted to know how can I convert Interop.range Value2 to a one dimensional string array[]
This is from the watch returning Range.Value2

```
[1, 1] "Somestring" object {string}
[1, 2]  null    object
[1, 3]  null    object
[1, 4]  null    object
[1, 5]  0.0 object {double}
[1, 6]  0.0 object {double}
[1, 7]  0.0 object {double}
```

Comment: I tried:
    string[] str = new string[20];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(oRngListRow.Value2, 1, str, 1, 20);

Comment: I also tried    var obj = oRngListRow.Value2 as IEnumerable<object>;
                string[] arr = (obj).Cast<object>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                 .ToArray();

Comment: You can't *cast* between the two. Build a new string array and copy over the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you have, but try

```
string[] arr = oRngListRow.Value2.Cast<object>()
    .Select(x => x == null ? null : x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

close to what you had in your own comment.

---

Since C# 6.0 (from 2015), this can also be written:

```
string[] arr = oRngListRow.Value2.Cast<object>()
    .Select(x => x?.ToString()).ToArray();
```

If you want an empty string instead, in the case where the entry is a null object, you can use string interpolation, also since C# 6.0:

```
string[] arr = oRngListRow.Value2.Cast<object>()
    .Select(x => $"{x}").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.  For some reason, Excel Interop does not like Linq.

```
        var list = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            list.Add((oRngListRow.Cells[1, i].Value2 ?? string.Empty).ToString());
        }
```